# disabling the Allow/Deny request for location

Tags: vb.net, html

In my web app I am displaying weather data based on the html5 location service to retrieve latitude and longitude which I then use for weather retrieval. The problem lies in that the first time a page is loaded the browser asks for Allow/Deny to use location, is there a way to programmatically disable that feature?

Comment: If there were, it wouldn't be of much use to have it in the first place, now would it?

Comment: Agreed, but that doesnt mean there isnt a way around it

Comment: If there is, that is called a security vulnerability, unless you have the user explicitly grant permanent permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your users grant your site permanent permission to access location information. I assume it is done in the [same place](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/) where you can revoke this permission as well (using Firefox, for example):

> How do I undo a permission granted to a site?
>
> If you've given Firefox permission to always give your location to a
>   site and later change your mind, you can easily revoke that
>   permission. Here's how:
>
> ```
> Navigate to the site to which you've given permission
> Go to the Tools menu, then select Page Info
> Select the Permissions tab
> Change the setting for Share Location
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because it is your browser that blocks the request.

Answer (score 0):

Current web implementation requires exclusive allow and deny feature by browser , you can rather put in an algo of ip tracking using geolocation to detect the location of the user, which though not precisely the same but will still improve your results.
Also you can use entering of pincode by user or something similar.